# Best Way to Filter Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data that looks like this:

```
var data = [
    {item1: 123, item2: "name", item3: "id"},
    {item1: 234, item2: "other"},
    {item1: 456, item2: "another"},
    {item1: 789, item2: "again"}
]
```

How do I loop through and find if item3 is there, and if it isn't, fill it with something.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use if "item" == undefined but it didn't seem to work @henrikstroem

Answer (score 2):

You could use a normal for loop iterating over the array elements or follow a [functional](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var data = [
    {item1: 123, item2: "name", item3: "id"},
    {item1: 234, item2: "other"},
    {item1: 456, item2: "another"},
    {item1: 789, item2: "again"}
];

// 1. Using Array.foreach:
data.forEach(function(element) {
  if (!element.hasOwnProperty('item3')) element.item3 = "default";
});

// 2. Using Array.map: 
data = data.map(function(element) {
  if (!element.hasOwnProperty('item3')) element.item3 = "default";
  return element;
});

// 3. Using a for-loop:
for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; ++i) {
  if (!data[i].hasOwnProperty('item3')) data[i].item3 = "default";
}

console.log(data);
```

I recommend 1 or 2 if you don't want to keep the original data array.

**Performance on Chrome 48 (similar in Firefox 44, 100000 runs):**

- Array.foreach() 520ms
- Array.map() 790ms
- for-loop 2700ms

Possible explanation: Since the Array.foreach() and Array.map() callbacks do not reference anything outside the passed parameters, modern JITs can cache the passed inline function and outperform the traditional for-loop.

Comment: Too bad it is down for the moment :/

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forEach(function (item) { 
    if (item.item3 == undefined) item.item3 = "filled with something"
});
```

Comment: What if `item.item3` is falsy?

Comment: `typeof item.item3 === 'undefined'`

Comment: Fair enough, I'll update it, but the requirements were a bit sparse

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate over each item, in order, in the array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //check to see if item3 is NOT there
    if(typeof data[i].item3 === 'undefined') {
        data[i].item3 = 'default value';
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `data[i].item3` is `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `for...of` loop:

```
for (const element of data) {
  if (!("item3" in element)) {
    element.item3 = "something"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through and check if a key exists.

```
var data = [
    { item1: 123, item2: "name", item3: "id" },
    { item1: 234, item2: "other" },
    { item1: 456, item2: "another" },
    { item1: 789, item2: "again" }
]

function fillIn(data, key, value)
{
    for(var i = 0, numRows = data.length; i < numRows; ++i)
    {
        if(!(key in data[i])) data[i][key] = value;
    }
}

fillIn(data, "item3", "dingo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following loop:

```
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            for (var item in data[i]){
            if (item == "item3"){
                console.log("found");
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var elem in data){
    var isPresent = 0;
    for(var key in data[elem]){
        if(key == "item3"){
            isPresent = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!isPresent){
        //Whatever function you need
    }
```

This should be it.

Comment: Where did you get `payload` from?

Comment: Sorry, it was from a function I'd previously created. I fixed it. @IMTheNachoMan

Comment: You still never create the key if it's not present.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Not quite understanding what you're getting at

Comment: You set `isPresent` to 1 if the key `item3` exists. Then you check if it is present. But then you never create the `item3` key which is what OP wants. I think inside the `if` block you would want `data[elem]["item3"] = "blah";`

Comment: Right, but I'm assuming he would know how to do so

Answer (score 0):

While the specification is filtering for objects without `item3`, i suggest to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var data = [{ item1: 123, item2: "name", item3: "id" }, { item1: 234, item2: "other" }, { item1: 456, item2: "another" }, { item1: 789, item2: "again" }],
    dataWithoutItem3 = data.filter(function (o) {
        return !('item3' in o);
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dataWithoutItem3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it;

```js
var data = [
    {item1: 123, item2: "name", item3: "id"},
    {item1: 234, item2: "other"},
    {item1: 456, item2: "another"},
    {item1: 789, item2: "again"}
],
 newData = data.map(o => !o.item3 ? (o.item3 = "something",o) : o);

console.log(newData);
```